# NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED when several requests using SQLite on Mozilla plateform

Tags: sqlite, xul, thunderbird

I'm trying to use Storage mechanism in Mozilla platform (in thundebird 3.0).

The following code is used after each test to erase the table present in the database:

```js
function tearDown()
{
  let database = new Database();

  let req1 = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
  let statement = database.connection.createStatement(req1);
  let tables = [];
  while(statement.executeStep()) {
    tables.push(statement.row.name);
  }
  statement.reset();
  for(table in tables) {
    let req2 = "DROP TABLE " + tables[table];
    database.connection.executeSimpleSQL(req2);
  }
}
```

But I've an error during `executeSimpleSQL` of `req2` (`NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED`), It seems that SQLite doesn't release the lock from the first statement. I've tried `reset()`, `finalize()`, but nothing works. How can I properly release the lock of the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself: I forgot to release a previous statement in previous code of my application.

Final story: when you use

```
statement.executeStep()
```

Check:

- be sure that the last call of this statement return false
- or never forgot to release it:

  statement.reset();

Answer (score 1):

```
var statement = dbConn.createStatement("SELECT COUNT(name) AS nameOcurrences FROM Table1 WHERE name = '" + aName + "';");

var occurrences;

while(statement.executeStep()) {
   occurrences = statement.row.nameOcurrences; 
}
```